# phpexcel stylesheet cells going right floating

Tags: phpexcel

1. > i am using Php excelscript download bye git hub i get some ERRORS

> which i ask and found result but having error excel sheet cell not
>   going right way look at below image i want to set it as excel bu not
>   found any style sheet and don't know how to set it i need help:)) and
>   set it to perfect position. http://i43.tinypic.com/3476xr4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles are defined dynamically by the writer script because they're completely dependent on the styling defined in the Excel file itself. You're using an Open Source library, which means that you can look at the code that handles the file generation in Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php and see how it defines the styles there; and even modify it yourself if you want something different.

Comment: i am want default style. and i try clear all cells but not found any solution when i type text in 1 cel then cell border change place. i mean i dont modify styling but still not found same style like excel.:((( please help me to solve this bcoz i did not get default style thats y .:((

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand the problem that you are having: if the Excel style for a cell is yellow background, then you get a yellow background when rendered as HTML; if the text style is bold, and using a 2 decimal places money format in Excel; then you should see it in bold and as a currency to 2dp when rendered in HTML. Default style is no border, black normal text at 10pt Calibri on a white background, and that's what you should see rendered in HTML unless you've changed the default styles for the workbook: cell borders only appear if you've specified cell borders

Comment: :-))) done. and  i dont use t..hank word mabe last time i block here thats y. and last problem if u give me jquery tabs script ? bcoz i have and ai know about this i use many time but here foreach loop make problem thast y . give me tasb script which is fit for this. tabs navigation:))